# Identifying HTML elements on a web page

Tags: r

I found some sample R scripts online.  Both do exactly what I would expect, but I'm not exactly sure how to interpret the HTML, so I can't really back-solve these two scripts.  Please explain this to me.

How does R know to look for the table named `'elo'` in the example below?

```
elo = htmlParse("http://tennisabstract.com/reports/atp_elo_ratings.html")
class(elo)
elo.table = readHTMLTable(elo, header=T, which=5,stringsAsFactors=F)
elo.table
```

Similarly, how does R know to look for the html nodes named `'#gsc_a_b .gsc_a_c'` in the example below?

```
library(rvest)
library(ggplot2)

page <- read_html("https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=sTR9SIQAAAAJ&hl=en&oi=ao")

citations <- page %>% html_nodes ("#gsc_a_b .gsc_a_c") %>% html_text()%>%as.numeric()

# citations 
# 148 96 79 64 57 57 57 55 52 50 48 37 34 33 30 28 26 25 23 22 

barplot(citations, main="How many times has each paper been cited?", ylab='Number of citations', col="skyblue", xlab="")
```

If I go to both pages and hit F12, I can see all the HTML behind each page.  I searched for `elo` in the first URL and `#gsc_a_b .gsc_a_c` in the second URL.  I don't see these variables anywhere!  I thought I know how to read HTML, but this is making me think I don't know how it works.  Or, is there some special trick to this?

I'd appreciate any/all insight into how R interprets HTML in these two scenarios.

Comment: You def need to heed @warmoverflow's advice. If you're going to scrape HTML, you need to learn HTML. No easy path to knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

For your first example, `elo` is a variable name, not an HTML element. The code reads the whole page into the elo variable, and extracts the table element using `readHTMLTable`.

For your second example, you need to know a bit more about CSS selectors. `.gsc_a_b` means an HTML element with `class` of `gsc_a_b`. `#gsc_a_c` means an HTML element with `id` of `gsc_a_c`.

Comment: Ah!  Now it makes sense.  Thanks warmoverflow!